# JQuery delegate multiples issue

Tags: jquery, html, delegates

I have a delegate Jquery function of which is working but each time i click a field it increases the number of times the delegate function executes.

Example: 3 field inputs, i click one, which the delegate responds to, but then if i click the next field or even the same field the function then operates twice, and 3 times for 3 times etc.

`Why is this happening and how can i prevent this?`

I have tried using `return false` on both parts, the function and the delegate function, but that has not helped at all.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/7q6Se/)

**The HTML**

```
<div class="input-group marg_5">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Article Title</span>
          <input id='new_vid_form_title' type="text" class="form-control vid_form" placeholder="Article Title" autocomplete='off'>
          <span class="input-group-addon"> 
            <span id="new_vid_form_title_status" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk orange pointer status_box" title="Required field"></span>
          </span>
</div>

<div class="input-group marg_5">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Short Desc.</span>
          <input id="new_vid_form_shortDesc_status" type="text" class="form-control vid_form" placeholder="Short Description" autocomplete='off'>
          <span class="input-group-addon"> 
            <span id="new_vid_form_shortDesc_status" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk orange pointer status_box" title="Required field"></span>
          </span>
</div>

         <hr />

<div class="input-group marg_5">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Youtube ID</span>
          <input id="new_vid_form_youtubeID_status" type="text" class="form-control vid_form" placeholder="Youtube Video ID | watch?v=' this bit ' " autocomplete='off'>
          <span class="input-group-addon"> 
            <span id="new_vid_form_youtubeID_status" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk orange pointer status_box" title="Required field"></span>
          </span>
</div>

         <hr />
```

**The JQuery/JS**

```
function new_vid() {
    $("div").delegate("input","click",function(){
        $('.vid_form').keyup( function() {
                  alert('ddd'); 
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: You should not be installing a new keyup handler on every click - that is your problem.

Comment: Im not sure i follow? I have a function of which needs to operate based on keyup. How do i go about making delegate accommodate for this function correctly? @jfriend00

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish in your page, but hopefully you can understand that EVERY time a click event occurs, you are installing yet another `.keyup()` handler and that's why you are getting N handlers called on each key so obviously this code isn't right.  I don't know what you really expect to have happen on a click.

Comment: Yes, i think i have been thinking about delegate in the wrong manner. I require it as i am loading divs with ajax into the DOM and the script controlling them is loaded beforehand. I thought delegate was the correct way to go, but perhaps i should try on() instead? @jfriend00

Comment: `.on()` isn't going to work any differently in this regard than `.delegate()`.  That isn't your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, although I think you're using delegate here to make sure the code happens once, the code contained within it happens multiple times. To clarify: every time you click an input contained within a div, it executes the body of the **delegate** function. The result? You attach a keyup handler. Click 2? You attach a keyup handler. Click 3? Same thing.

What you have inside the function body is a binding to a keyup event without any destruction of that keyup event in the future, thus the multiple executions of that event. You'd be better off doing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/notsoluckycharm/NYdVA/

```
$("div").delegate(".vid_form","keyup",function(){
   alert('ddd'); 
 });
```

Now, delegate is deprecated but I answered it the way you've presented it.

Newer versions of jQuery would look like this

```
$("div").on("keyup",".vid_form",function(){
   alert('ddd'); 
 });
```

Comment: Yes, my use for delegate was to ensure it ran as im loading div cointent into the DOM after the js file has been loaded. That caused the script to break and thus why i was trying to use delegate. The `on()` method you posted works exactly as i was trying to get `delegate` to work. I was just going about it with the wrong method. Many thanks!